# Difference between <% ... %> and <%= .. %> in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have test method in helpers/application_helper.rb file:

```
def test
  concat("Hello world")
end
```

Then, in index.html.erb I call as:

```
Blah
<% test %>
```

The browser display:

> Blah
>   Hello world

It's normally, but if I change

```
<%= test %>
```

the browser display:

> Blah Hello worldBlah Hello world

It duplicate all of page. I don't know why?
What difference between them?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using `concat`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-concat), `concat` is only supposed to be used within a `<% %>` code block. When you use it in a `<%= %>` code block, you see it twice because `concat` appends the provided text to the output buffer, but then it also returns the entire output buffer back to your helper method, which is then output by the `<%=`, causing your entire page to be duplicated.

Normally, you should not need to use `concat` much if at all (I've never come across a situation where I needed it). In your helper, you can just do this:

```
def test
  "Hello world"
end
```

And then use `<%= test %>` in your view.

Comment: Thanks Dylan Markow, can you show me <% %> and <%= %> are used in what case? I use much concat in my helper method, is it good? If not, how to solve? (I use concat to write html tag in helper method)

Answer (score 16):

Normally a <% %> is a snippet of Rails code (ie starting a conditional, ending a conditional, etc), whereas <%= %> actually evaluates an expression and returns a value to the page.

Answer (score 11):

**What's the Difference?**

`<% %>` let's you evaluate the rails code in your view

`<%= %>` let's you evaluate the rails code in your view AND prints out a result on the page

**Example #1:** 
The equal sign is analogous to "puts" so:

```
<%= "Hello %>
```

...is the same as:

```
<% puts "Hello" %>
```

**Example #2:**

```
<% if !user_signed_in? %>
    <%= "This text shows up on the page" %>
<% end %> 

#returns "This text shows up on the page" if the user is signed in
```

Comment: I was looking for <%- -%>. Do you know by any chance what it does?

Answer (score 5):

It is just like this

```
<% execute this code and display nothing %>
```

and

```
<%= execute this code and display the result in the view %>
```

Answer (score -1):

See this:

```
<%= You need to do this %>
<% You shouldn't do this %>
```