# Printed texts in a browser using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I'm new to Ruby on Rails. My code runs well. My problem is there are some texts displaying on the webpage and I dont know where that came from.
Here is the screenshot of it:
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0f32dhw7f4

here is my add controller

```
class AddsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @add = Add.new
  end

  def create
    @add = Add.new(params.require(:add).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email))
    if @add.save
      redirect_to(:controller=>'home')
    else
      render 'new'
    end 
  end

  def edit
    @add = Add.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @add = Add.find(params[:id])
    if @add.update(params.require(:add).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email))
      redirect_to(:controller=>'home')
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @add = Add.find(params[:id])
    @add.destroy
    redirect_to(:controller=>'home')
  end

end
```

This is my app/views/home file

```
 <ul id="nav">
    <li><%= link_to "Home", controller: "home" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Products", controller: "products" %></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <h1>Lists</h1> 
  <%= link_to "Add", new_add_path, :class=> 'btn btn-success' %>
  <br />
  <br />

  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>First Name </th>
      <th>Last Name </th>
      <th>Email </th>
      <th>Options </th>
    </tr>
    <%= @adds.each do |adds| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= adds.first_name%></td>
        <td><%= adds.last_name %></td>
        <td><%= adds.email %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_add_path(adds) %> |
            <%= link_to "Delete", add_path(adds),
                                 method: :delete, data:{confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this?'} %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
```

my home controller

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @adds = Add.all
  end
end
```

Can someone figured me out on this?

Comment: check your application layout, `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

Comment: i already checked! whats been added there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view while iterating array, you have used <%= @adds %> change the iterating part of code as below

```
<% @adds.each do |adds| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= adds.first_name%></td>
        <td><%= adds.last_name %></td>
        <td><%= adds.email %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_add_path(adds) %> |
            <%= link_to "Delete", add_path(adds),
                                 method: :delete, data:{confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this?'} %>
        </td>
      </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
<%= @adds.each do |adds| %>
```

To

```
<% @adds.each do |adds| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are using `<%= %>` instead of `<% %>` in iterating part.

change `<%= @adds.each do |adds| %>` to `<% @adds.each do |adds| %>`

For More information on Rails tags see [This](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html)

And If you want to know the Difference between <%= and <% see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997523/difference-between-and-in-rails-3)