# How do I remove unexpected output from my Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning Ruby on Rails and am writing a simple application.

I have a scaffold task and workBlock. The task has many work blocks. A work block belongs to task. In the task view- show, I am trying to display the task's associated workblocks.

The result is:

```
>     Work Blocks:
>     
>     2
>     [#<WorkBlock id: 1, name: "2", start_time: "2014-07-23 22:52:00", end_time: "2014-07-23 22:52:00", hours_spent: nil, task_id: 33,
> created_at: "2014-07-23 22:52:26", updated_at: "2014-07-23 22:52:26">]
```

I don't know why everything below '2' is showing up, and have no idea how to get rid of it.

I also don't know if this has something to do with the datetime type involved.

Here is the code:

This is in task show.

```
<p>
</br></br>

<h2>Work Blocks: </h2>


<%= @task.work_blocks.each do |work_block| %>


<li><%=link_to work_block.name , work_block_path(work_block)%></br>


<%end%>

</p>
<p>
 <%=link_to 'Create Work Block', new_work_block_path(:task_id => @task.id)%>
</p>
```

This is in workBlock model:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: work_blocks
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  name        :string(255)
#  start_time  :datetime
#  end_time    :datetime
#  hours_spent :integer
#  task_id     :integer
#  created_at  :datetime
#  updated_at  :datetime
#
class WorkBlock < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :tasks
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace your `each` block with:

```
<% @task.work_blocks.each do |work_block| %>
  <li><%=link_to work_block.name , work_block_path(work_block)%></br>
<%end%>
```

You were outputting the evaluation of `each` block as well by using `<%= @task.work_blocks.each...%>`.

Have a look at the answers on [Difference between <% … %> and <%= .. %> in rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997523/difference-between-and-in-rails-3) for details on the two tags.

Answer (score 0):

**Output Tags**

I had this problem when I first started Rails - if you use the `.each` method with the `<%= output tags %>`, you'll basically get the outputted list of data that you're trying to loop through.

The way to fix this is to use the `<% non output tags %>`, so that Ruby doesn't output the loop itself, rather the contents of the loop:

```
<% @task.work_blocks.each do |work_block| %>
   <li><%=link_to work_block.name , work_block_path(work_block)%></li>
<% end %>
```

--

**HTML**

By-the-by, your HTML tags are not formatted correctly

A general rule of HTML formatting is you will need to close the tags you use. When you use a `<li>` element, you generally have to close it with `</li>`, otherwise you get a LOAD of problems with your HTML rendering in your browser.

I would strongly advise you read up on how to correctly format the HTML elements on your page, as to ensure you're able to get it all working correctly