# View printing contents of Variable Ruby on rails for no apparent reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There seems to be something weird going on with my rails app. I have an action in my controller called Info that sends a request to a webservice, and then renders the data in a neatly formatted way corresponding view.

The problem is that for some reason it decides it will be fun to print the content of @destinations at the end of the loop. See the example code below. Obviously I've simplified the code a bit for readability,  but the problem still occurs with the below code. If there is any other code that is relevant, let me know and I will update the question.

CONTROLLER

```
def info
  /*Execute some WebService call here and convert into Hash*/
  @destinations = ros.data.places.map{|dest| dest.name}

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :layout => false }
  end
end
```

VIEW

```
<%=@destinations.each do |dest| %>
  <%=dest%>
<%end%>
```

OUTPUT

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
      Laos Latvia ["Laos", "Latvia"]
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove unexpected output from my Rails application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922599/how-do-i-remove-unexpected-output-from-my-rails-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change

```
<%=@destinations.each do |dest| %>
```

to

```
<% @destinations.each do |dest| %>
```

See the redundant `=`?